# ASP.NET Core - Use both UseDeveloperExceptionPage() and custom logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, .net-core

I have the following code in my ASP.NET Core application to handle errors:

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
            {
                builder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                    var loggingService = context.RequestServices.GetService<ILoggingService>();
                    var exceptionFeature = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (exceptionFeature != null)
                    {
                        Exception ex = exceptionFeature.Error;
                        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message + "   " + ex.StackTrace);
                        loggingService.Error(ex);
                    }
                });
        }
```

However, when being in a `Development` environment, I would like to use both the `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` and the custom error handling for DB logging. But it seems that this does not work (the `UseExceptionHandler()` disables the functionality of `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()`).

Is there any way to achieve this, without writing the `UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` code form scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For built-in `UseDeveloperExceptionPage`, it did not expose any extension method to custom the error process, you could try implement your own middleware to log the error like

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
};
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next.Invoke();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //var loggingService = context.RequestServices.GetService<ILoggingService>();
        //loggingService.Error(ex);
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message + " My " + ex.StackTrace);
        throw;
    }

});
```

Comment: In case you are interested there is now options to add some custom processing into the built in UseDeveloperExceptionPage. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with this and couldn't find any documentation on the subject however from looking at the source code I did find there is a way to add some logging into the Developer ExceptionPage. The source code is here and I will make some references to parts of it: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/DeveloperExceptionPage/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.cs

The part we care about is this:

```
    _exceptionHandler = DisplayException;

    foreach (var filter in filters.Reverse())
    {
        var nextFilter = _exceptionHandler;
        _exceptionHandler = errorContext => filter.HandleExceptionAsync(errorContext, nextFilter);
    }
```

Essentially it will take a set of filters and put them into a pipeline before the default DisplayExecution is run.

The filters are passed in as `IEnumerable<IDeveloperPageExceptionFilter>` by DI which means all we need to do is add our own class that implements `IDeveloperPageExceptionFilter` and it will be executed. Here is an example filter from my testing of this:

```
public class LoggingDeveloperPageExceptionFilter : IDeveloperPageExceptionFilter
{
    private readonly ILogService _logService;
    public LoggingDeveloperPageExceptionFilter(ILogService logService)
    {
        _logService = logService;
    }
    public Task HandleExceptionAsync(ErrorContext errorContext, Func<ErrorContext, Task> next)
    {
        _logService.Error(errorContext.Exception);
        return next(errorContext);
    }
}
```

And this is registered in my startup.cs as such:

```
services.AddSingleton<IDeveloperPageExceptionFilter, LoggingDeveloperPageExceptionFilter>();
```

So in this case it will call my error logging in log service passing the exception in and then call the next item in the processing chain. Since I only have one `next` for me will be the original `DisplayException` which does all our nice pretty error output.